# How do I get the id of a clicked parent element in a card?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make certain "cards" that display next to each other, and when the card is clicked, I want to get the id of the card. However, my function gets the id of the child elements when I click it, which is undefined, rather than of the parent card, unless I click on the border of the card div. How do I make sure it gets the id of the card specifically?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="parentCard" onclick="getID(event)">
  <div id="child1">I'm a child</div>
  <div id="text">
    <p>Text 1</p>
    <p>Text 2</p>
    <p>Text 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function getID(event){
  console.log(event.target.id);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) which

> Identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to `event.target` which identifies the element on which the event occurred.

```js
function getID(event){
  console.log(event.currentTarget.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="parentCard" onclick="getID(event)">
  <div id="child1">I'm a child</div>
  <div id="text">
    <p>Text 1</p>
    <p>Text 2</p>
    <p>Text 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want the ID of `parentCard`. They want the ID of the parent card of the element they clicked on if it's not a card div.

Comment: @Andy if they add a listener to a card element, then that card element is obtained with `currentTarget`. The answer is correct in so far that if you add the listener *on a card* then you can get the card with `currentTarget`. Of course, if you have N cards, you'd have to attach the [same] listener to each card for this to work, and if N is a lot then perhaps another solution is better. But I maintain still that the answer is correct, within the confines of its assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

Grab the target element of the event (the element that was clicked).

Here I've used [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the `id`, `tagName`, and `parentNode` properties from the target.

If the clicked element is a card div element log the id, otherwise log the id of the parent element.

Note: this assumes that the cards won't have nested HTML any deeper than they are in your example or `parentNode` won't apply to the right parent element.

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parentCard');
parent.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {
  const { id, tagName, parentNode } = e.target;
  console.log(tagName === 'DIV' ? id : parentNode.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="parentCard">
  <div id="child1">I'm a child</div>
  <div id="text">
    <p>Text 1</p>
    <p>Text 2</p>
    <p>Text 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Only works if a *child* element of a card is clicked. This will not work for any descendant of a card that is not a direct child of the latter. You will need to traverse the list of ancestors of whichever element is clicked and see if you've reached the card element (or there was none in the ancestor list).

Comment: Indeed, *now* you have.

Answer (score 2):

Every time the user clicks somewhere on a page, the user agent will determine which "non-compound" element was clicked on and fire an event of type "click" event with *that* element as event target.

A "non-compound" element here means one that does not have descendant *elements* (it may have descendant *nodes*, like text, for instance).

Since your cards will typically be compound elements -- containing other elements (which may contain other elements in turn) -- there is no guarantees about which of these elements will be the click event `target`.

The user agent is a machine and cannot think for you and know that that the user "clicks on a card". If the card contains a button or a link or an image, all the user agent will do is tell you which of these the user has clicked on, through the means of the `target` property on the event -- *you* need to determine the fact that from your perspective, a card was clicked on.

There are at least two ways to determine said fact:

1. Find out which card element is or contains the clicked element:

   ```
   function get_card(element) {
       for(; element; element = element.parentElement) {
           if(is_card(element)) return element;
       }
   }
   ```

   How do you know, traversing ancestor list, that an element is a card? As far as the document object model is concerned, it's just a `div` element, with an `onclick` attribute and an ID. You may have `div` elements with defined `id` and `onclick` attributes in your document that are not cards.

   Adding a class to an element is a natural way to, well, classify it:

   ```
   <div class="card">
       <!-- descendant elements -->
   </div>
   ```

   With the above we decide and now assume that every card element will include "card" in the list of its class names. Now you can write your `is_card` function (used in `get_card`), as follows:

   ```
   function is_card(element) {
       return element.classList.contains("card");
   }
   ```

   With a working `get_card(element)` function in your program you can now reliably answer the question "which card, if any, contains `element`?". In combination with a single event listener on, say, the `window` object you can now know which card the user clicks on:

   ```
   addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
       var card = get_card(ev.target);
       if(card) {
           /// A card was clicked, do something about it.
       }
   }
   ```

   As you can see, you don't even need to add listeners to every card, adding one to one container element of your choice (or `window` as is the case above) is all you need with this solution.

   Now, this is a case of a so-called linear-time algorithm -- the "deeper" your cards (descendant elements containing other descendant elements in turn), the longer average time it will take to locate the card for a descendant element. But it's nothing to worry about with "click" handling and performance of modern JavaScript runtimes, if I am allowed to be general here.
2. Use the [so-far experimental] CSS4 and the [`pointer-events: none`](http://wiki.csswg.org/spec/css4-ui#pointer-events) rule for card's children. Assuming every card includes the class "card", you can specify that no descendant element will have pointer events enabled -- these will never fire "click" events, the card element will instead:

   ```
   .card > * {
       pointer-events: none;
   }
   ```

   The support for `pointer-events` is still experimental but I know that recent Google Chrome and Firefox do support it. You have to be careful here though -- like, are you prepared to disable interactivity for some of card's elements? What if you have form elements there, which are typically interactive? You need to assess these kind of requirements yourself.

There is a third solution, but I consider it inferior to at least the first solution. For the sake of completeness, assigning an event listener on each card may be wasteful, especially if there are many cards on each page. However, in any case, if you attach a "click" listener to a card like you yourself did, the element the listener for the event type "click" was added to, is available with the `ev.currentTarget` property! Meaning that no matter which descendant element fires the "click" event, the event will reach the card element, through its [capture](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-capturing_phase) and [bubbling](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-bubbling_phase) phases, and the `currentTarget` property value will always refer to the element the listener is added to -- in this case the card element. Of course, this solution implies that the listener is attached to *every* card.